# Gazebo stuck at loading your world

Tags: macos, ros, gazebo-simu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYFSq.jpg
I am trying to set up ROS and Gazebo in a VM running Ubuntu. 
The goal is that I want to simulate Turtlebot with the open manipulator.

I installed everything without any issues. 
Though I am not able to launch the Turtlebot environment on Gazebo (like here: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/)

$roslaunch turtlebot3_fake turtlebot3_fake.launch
results in Gazebo staying forever in the state loading your world. After some time, it stops responding. 
Launching the empty world however works.

I am using ROS 1 with Gazebo 7.0

My hardware setup:
MacBook Pro 13" 2019 with 16 GB RAM
Parallels VM: 3D virtual. ON, no performance limit, 4 CPU kernels, 12 GB RAM enabled

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every change you made source your bash and make sure to run :

```
          catkin make
```

if you've done this already then check if ros is installed properly by running

```
           roscore
```

on one terminal and let it stay running.
After that try to launch your turtlebot on another terminal.
If it doesnt work even you have installed all of the needed things, i think the problem is with your VM, id recommend you to run ROS on Ubuntu running USB Stick.

Comment: I resloved it. Gazebo 7 wasn't compatible with my graphics card on my mac it seems. I decided to go with Ros 2 and Gazebo 9 and it worked perfectly then

Comment: Im Glad that youve solved it, thank you very much by the way for choosing it as an "answer".

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~/.gazebo/
mkdir  models
cd models/
wget http://file.ncnynl.com/ros/gazebo_models.txt
wget -i gazebo_models.txt
ls model.tar.g* | xargs -n1 tar xzvf
```

try this gazebo try to download to packages that's why it waits u need internet for that this may take few mins